# sfdx.exe deploy WorkflowRule fails with "not found in zipped directory"

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, workflowrule, sfdx-error

I am working with sfdx

Trying to deploy a changed workflow from my sandbox to production

I am getting the workflow with no problems with this command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m WorkflowRule:myObject__c.myWorkflowRule
```

Now I try to deploy and I always get an error:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -m WorkflowRule:myObject__c.myWorkflowRule
```

The error:

> An object 'myObject__c.myWorkflowRule' of type
> WorkflowRule was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped
> directory

Is there something I am doing wrong?

If is is a bug - Is there a different way to deploy WorkflowRules with sfdx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how WorkflowRule files are constructed, you can't deploy just one rule at a time. I'm not sure if it's a bug or a limitation, but I can say that you need to deploy all the workflow rules for an Object if you're using the CLI; you can't deploy just one.

Try:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/workflows/myObject__c.workflow-meta.xml
```

Replace the path with the appropriate path for your project.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. this works, but it is really bad if I want later on to automate this process. also - do you know if I need to get all related components of the workflow rule (alerts, updates etc.)? otherwise deploy with part of them can remove the missing parts?

Comment: @ItaiShmida (a) Deploying a rule already deployed should have no effect; you can automate this. (b) You should retrieve all parts (e.g. `force:source:retrieve -m Workflow`) to make sure you don't miss anything.

Comment: 'force:source:retrieve -m "Workflow:work flow name" does not work do I have to get all workflows for that?

Comment: @ItaiShmida You can get `Workflow` (no qualifiers) for all objects, or `Workflow:ObjectName` to get all workflows on a single object, including all attached field updates, outbound messages, etc.

Comment: This is too risky, we have sandboxes that admins are working on and sometimes not refreshed and they have many differences from production. With this approach I can deploy components that are not needed. So actually the current solution from Salesforce is not good enough. This is also on email templates, @sfdcfox do you know any other problematic component types?

Comment: @ItaiShmida If it's risky, that indicates there's a problem with your development cycle. This has always been the risk, going back a couple of decades now. It's the reason why we have Salesforce DX, to help mitigate that risk, but in order to do that, you're going to have to adopt a more disciplined approach to development.